# How to install ireport designer in Centos

Tags: centos, ireport

We want to install ireport designer in centos. How to do that. and 
does centos will provide GUI for report generator.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to install iReport in Linux(centos) machine -

1:- Download iReport-5.5.1.tar.gz from bellow [Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport/iReport-5.5.1/iReport-5.5.1.tar.gz/download).

2:- After downloading iReport go to the directory where you have downloaded it. In my case it is in Downloads directory.

```
 $ cd /Downloads/
```

And if you want to copy in other directory you can use mv (move) or cp (copy) command.

```
 $ mv/Downloads/ iReport-5.5.1.tar.gz     /opt/ iReport-5.5.1.tar.gz
```

3:- Extract iReport-5.5.1 directory from zipped file using bellow command.

```
 $ tar -zxvf iReport-5.5.1.tar.gz
```

4:- Now to start iReport open a terminal and type the bellow command.

```
 $ /Downloads/iReport-5.5.1/bin/ireport
```

Now if your iReport starts that means you have successfully installed iReport.

You can see the full post on my [blog](http://passionfordata.blogspot.in).

Comment: Thanks sharad. We are also planning to install jasperreport server community edition in centos. I had installed jasperreport server in centos and when i put .jrxml report in the server. when i click run to execute a report it is keep on loading.. Any help on this

Comment: No error message is displaying. getting one window and displaying loading.. it will load forever..

Comment: where to find logs in both windows and linux environments